# Finding root cause of redirect with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: redirect, browser, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am trying to debug a webpage with chrome developer tools and the page redirects to a pdf file after it loads. I checked JavaScript files and there is not any place that we redirect the page. I cannot find any related message in developer tool console or network tab.

I activated `event Listener Breakpoints` -> `beforeunload` but it stops at an external js file ([Placeholders.js](https://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/)) which is not related to redirecting.

Also, preserving Logs in network tab does not help me on finding root cause of redirect.

I am wondering how can I find the source of this redirect?

---

UPDATE: There is not any "refresh" meta tag in the html code.

Comment: Finally I found out that the response had a refresh meta tag and I could not find it. Surprisingly this meta tag works after jquery.append

Comment: @ChristosK.Thank you for your consideration but that question is about preserving network tab in chrome debugger tools and is not related to finding source of redirect.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of things you can do. You can use the `Event Listener Breakpoint -> Load - unload` and then when it breaks in the 3rd party library, right click and select `Blackbox Script`. The next time you play through the code, it should only break in your own code (assuming there are no other 3rd party libraries to blackbox).

Another option is to go to the Network tab and check the `Preserve Log` checkbox. This will persist all requests between page loads/navigation, so that you will be able to find the network request that returned the PDF response.

[image: Network tab]

Comment: I marked the 3rd party js file as black box, but, developer tool did not stop any where else after that. I think your suggested methods + checking the refresh Meta tag cover all refresh situations.

Comment: This doesn't help if the new URL is opened in a new tab. Seems that on a new tab it does not preserve the starting URL of that tab. Just the redirect result. Very odd. So there's no way to know what URL the new tab was opened at.